# Equivalence of definitions of a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I have a question adressing the "abstract" definition of a submanifold and the version in the special case of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is what I mean:

I looked up these two definitions of a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$:

1. A subset $M⊂\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a $k$-dimensional submanifold if for every $a∈ M$ there is an open neighborhood $U∈\mathbb{R}^n$ and smooth functions $f_1,\dots,f_{n-k}\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

- $M\cap U = \{x∈ U : f_1=\dots f_{n-k}(x)=0\}$
- $rank
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  \frac{∂ f_1}{∂ x_1} & \dots & \frac{∂ f_1}{∂ x_n}\\
  \vdots & & \vdots\\
  \frac{∂ f_{n-k}}{∂ x_1} & \dots & \frac{∂ f_{n-k}}{∂ x_n}\\
  \end{pmatrix} = n-k$

2. (Loring Wu, p. 100) A subset $M$ of a manifold $N$ of dimension $n$ is a regular submanifold of dimension $k$ if for every $p∈ M$ there is a coordinate neighborhood $(U,x^1,\dots,x^n)$ of $N$ such that $U\cap M$ is defined by the vanishing of $n-k$ of the coordinate functions.

So the second definition is more general than the first one by taking $N=\mathbb{R}^n$. What I don't understand where the rank condition in the first definition comes from. The "vanishing of the functions part" of the second definition is the same as in the first one. I am wondering how to imply the second condition. In short: Are these definitions equivalent by taking $N=\mathbb{R}^n$ and if yes, why?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No it’s not as simple as setting $N=\Bbb{R}^n$. To prove the equivalence, you need to use the inverse/implicit function theorem. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260456/568204) for four equivalent definitions and the proof of their equivalence (unfortunately I didn’t prove them in the same order, so you might need to do some extra work, but you should be able to extract a proof for the specific directions you need).

Comment: Similar to an earlier question [Equivalence of definitions of a submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4802577/89922)?

Comment: Not "similar". **Identical**.  They seem to have been tagged at the exact same time, down to the second, so it's probably some kind of glitch. You should remove the other one.

Comment: That's Loring Tu, not Wu. Yes, the definitions are equivalent, because you choose a chart on a neighborhood of a point in $N$, thereby making $N=\Bbb R^n$.